# Best method for attaching/creating Moss Wall Art on drywall

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

I'm looking to cover a wall with a seamless edge-to-edge moss art piece like this:

[image: Moss Wall]

This will be on an interior wall which I believe is plain drywall (any way to check it's not solid/concrete?), somewhat like the wall on the right in this hallway:

[image: Hallway]

To avoid too much damage or difficulty removing from the wall, I was imagining getting thin plywood panels [like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Handprint-1-8-in-x-2-ft-x-4-ft-Tempered-Hardboard-Actual-0-115-in-x-23-75-in-x-47-75-in-Project-Panel-109112/202585358) and attaching them to the wall and then gluing the moss to the plywood panels. I assume Home Depot can help me cut the panels to dimensions I need.

Is this a good method for accomplishing this? What's the best way to attach the panels to the wall? Can I use a nail gun or staple gun or do I need drywall anchors and screws?

Comment: @crip659, **answers go down there**.

Comment: John, you're asking several questions here, one of which is highly subjective. Please take the [tour] and see if you can revise to ask one specific question.

Comment: That first example is either preserved moss or fake moss. Came from https://www.articulturedesigns.com/preserved-faux-plant-walls

Answer (score 0):

Good chance it is drywall. To check just need a pin/nail/screw, and push. If it goes in it is drywall.

Find where the studs, use a stud finder, are in the wall(every ~16 inches) and use nails/screws to hold the panels(smaller holes).

Do not know if a big box store will cut to size, a real lumber store maybe, but thin plywood not hard to cut yourself with hand or power saws.